# Shell: how check if no .txt files exist in the directory?

Tags: bash, shell

I want to check if there are no .txt files in the current directory. How do I do this in the standard shell?

Requirements:

- Must work with any sh (not only bash)
- Must be efficient (a single line without multiple functions?)

In terms of simplicity, it should be as close as possible to something like:

```
#! /bin/sh

[ -f ./*.txt ] || echo "Not found!"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `find` can be a good choice here:

```
#!/bin/sh

res=
res=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.txt' -type f -print -quit)

[ -n "$res" ] || echo 'Not found!'
```

which can be shortened to:

```
#!/bin/sh

[ -n "$(find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.txt' -type f -print -quit)" ] || echo 'Not found!'
```

The advantage of this is that there are no shell globs, and `find` quits as soon as a `*.txt` *file* is found. You won't get any *Argument list too long* errors if there are too many `.txt` files, and it'll be faster too in this case.

Moreover, with `-type f` we are sure we only deal with files. Many answers involving globs will fail if there are no `.txt` files but a *directory* named `whatever.txt`.

---

As [@chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) states in a comment (thanks!), `-maxdepth` and `-quit` are not specified by POSIX, so this solution is not portable (`-printf` is not specified by POSIX either, but it's a trivial fix to replace `-printf` by `-print`).

To fix the `-quit` switch, we'll use `grep` as follows:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -type f | grep -q . || echo 'Not found!'
```

As soon as `grep` reads a character, it exits, closing the pipe, and `find` will quit too.
This will recurse in subdirectories (which might be a wanted behavior).

Otherwise, if you don't want recursion:

```
find . -type d \! -name . -prune \! -type d -o -name '*.txt' -type f | grep -q . || echo 'Not found!'
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `-printf` and `-maxdepth` are not part of the POSIX standard for `find`, if you need this to be completely portable.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
if ls ./*.txt > /dev/null
then
    echo "File Exists"
else
    echo "File Doesn't exists"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(echo *.txt | grep -q '*') && echo not found
```

Comment: `touch 'hello*world.txt'`. Surprise.

Comment: Right idea, wrong execution. `f=$(echo *.txt); case $f in "*.txt") echo not found ;; *) echo found ;; esac`

Answer (score 1):

Following

```
( for f in *.txt; do [ -f "$f" ] && exit; done; exit 1 )
```

`$?` will be 0 if `*.txt` matches anything, 1 otherwise.

(Assuming `*.txt` is treated literally when it matches nothing, which should be true in POSIX shell, but may be false if, for example, you are using `bash` and the `nullglob` option is set.)

(Update: I incorporated gniourf_gniourf's suggestions for handling non-regular files that `*.txt` might match.)

Comment: I think you mean `( for f in *.txt; do [ -f "$f" ] && exit; done )`. Otherwise, if a directory ending in `.txt` appears before an existing `.txt` file in the glob expansion, your command will wrongly return a failure.

Comment: To be sure about your assumption, just add `exit 1` after the `done` keyword.

Comment: `exit` with no argument is intentional. What I want is for the exit status of `[` to persist after the loop terminates. Initially, I just used `break`, but that always sets `$?` to 0. Instead, I use `exit` to break out of the subshell with whatever `$?` was from the previous (`[`) command. (With your first suggestion, the loop will iterate over all matching files, instead of terminating as soon as it determines if `*.txt` matched any files or not.) (I really which `bash` had some sort of `glob` operator.)

Comment: I guess you overlooked my comment. It's about `[ -f "$f" ]; exit` versus `[ -f "$f" ] && exit`. Try, in an empty directory: `mkdir a.txt; touch z.txt` followed by your command. It will wrongly return a failure.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see that now.

Answer (score 0):

```
[ `printf *.txt` = '*.txt' ]
```

returns the answer to the OP question

Edit: explicit is better than implicit

```
[ `printf *.txt` = '*.txt' ] && echo "Not found!"
```

Edit #2, thank you  gniourf_gniourf

```
([ `printf *.txt` != '*.txt' ] || [ -f '*.txt' ]) && echo yes || echo no
```

Comment: This fails if there's a unique `txt` file named `*.txt`.

Comment: Of course you're right, I intended to mention but... thank you.

Comment: Oh, forgot to mention again! my last attempt fails if there is a directory named `whatever.txt`.